# Is it possible to `for` loop the `sapply` in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, optimization, sapply

I was wondering why my object `CI` doesn't correctly return the full (11 paired answers) outputs from the `for()` loop in the following function? Instead, the `CI` returns 11 single numbers.

```
N = 30 ; df = 118 ; d = 1

f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df) {
 abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - 
   alpha)
      }

 a = mapply(c, as.list(20:30), as.list(-20:-30), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) # a list of paired values

 CI <- numeric(length(a))

 for(i in 1:length(a)){

CI[i] = sapply(c(0.025, 0.975),
         function(x) optimize(f, interval = a[[i]], alpha = x, q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, tol = 1e-10)[[1]])

    }  

CI # just returns one paired of the 11 paired answers expected!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
N = 30 ; df = 118 ; d = 1

f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df) {
  abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - 
        alpha)
}

a = mapply(c, as.list(20:30), as.list(-20:-30), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) # a list of paired values

CI <- matrix(NA, 11,2)

for(i in 1:length(a)){

  CI[i,] = sapply(c(0.025, 0.975),
              function(x) optimize(f, interval = a[[i]], alpha = x, q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, tol = 1e-10)[[1]])

}  

CI
```

Comment: Thank you, while I'm waiting for system to allow me accept your answer, one question, how can I find the most frequently occurring answer (row) in the 11 rows?

Comment: @rnorouzian, the solutions are not exactly equal . see CI[4,] == CI[5]. So you may need to round them e.g. library(dplyr) ;summarise(group_by(as.data.frame(round(CI,4)),V1,V2),length(V2))